# Finite-state machine for external device

Tags: c++, serial-port, state-machine

I have learned about finite-state machine, read about different approaches and now I am going to implement it in my program as an exercise. My program is working with serial port device and my idea is to create class that could describe device status. Now I can not make a correct chain of connecting process. What I have meant:

1. User clicks connection button (e.g. switch)
2. State machine checks inner state and call connection function iff     inner state is "disconnected".
3. Depending on connection result state machine should be driven to     "connected" state or left "disconnected".
4. Fix user's switch in position "on" if "connected" and vice versa.

Is my chain correct?

Assuming so, I have tried to implement respective code. In my device class I have

```
void Device::doAction(Action action)
{
    switch (action) {
        case CONNECT:
            onConnect();
            break;

        case DISCONNECT:
            onDisconnect();
            break;
        .... 
}

void Device::onConnect()
{
    switch (getState()) {
        case DISCONNECTED: {
            setState(CONNECTED);
            break;
        }
        default:
            message("Device is already connected");
            break;
    }
}
```

With such approach I can not pass SerialPort's name with `doAction()` method cause it should be more universal for every action. Moreover in this case state will be set immediately without checking SerialPort's answer. Otherwise I could redefine

```
void Device::onConnect(const QString &port)
{
    switch (getState()) {
        case DISCONNECTED: {
            connectonRequest(port);
            break;
        }
    ....
    }
}
```

Then I could call new onConnect method directly from the ui. Then SerialPort's answer could be requested and state will be changed directly. Is this way is ok?

I would be appreciate for any advices.

Comment: Well, I assume that you need to add some kind of callback to your UI anyway. So you in the end are just circumventing the doAction function with its switch/case stuff entirely. I'd rather see this even as an advantage... If really is, though, depends a bit on the design of your GUI framework.

Comment: Other variants: `Device` could provide a setter for the connection string which gets called before doAction, or `Device` is initialised (constructor?) with some kind of address-provider (as interface), which your GUI class implements and lets the Device request the address to connect to.

Comment: If you're going to implement a finite-state machine, then normally the first things to do are (1) define the states, (2) define the state transitions, and (3) define the input/event(s) that trigger those transitions.  Your code snippets do not clearly convey such information about your state machine.